# Time machine restore is stuck after 3 hours

Tags: time-machine

I swapped out the hard drive on my old MacBook Pro. Installed Mountain Lion, then High Sierra. Now I’ve found my time machine password (available in Keychain Access app on my laptop but not in my iPhone passwords!!?! - thanks apple). So I’m trying to use the “system restore” from time machine. It’s stuck after 115GB (it’s done 10MB in the 20 mins I’ve been watching)

Should I give up? (The old drive was 256GB and full).

If I install OSX again and try Migration Assistant is that more likely to succeed? Will I lose a load of software? (eg PostgreSQL, python versions, docker, mongo and all the other web dev stuff I’ve put on there)